# How to make text input w/button autosize within responsive div

Tags: css, css-float

I am working with a website that is already responsive and works fine. I am trying to add a text input field with a button on the right and want the text input to autosize and the button to remain a fixed size.

The general HTML/CSS is:

```
<style>
  #container { width: 100%; }
  #text { float: left; }
  #btn { float: left; overflow: hidden; }
</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="text"><input type="text" /></div>
  <div id="btn"><input type="submit" /></div>
</div>
```

A visual:

```
+---------------- container (autosize) --------------+
| +------------------------------------------------+ |
| |        text (autosize)        |       btn      | |
| +------------------------------------------------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Desired behavior:

The container div will autosize depending on display width - this already gets handled. The btn div will size to exactly the width of the button - this already gets done also.

I would like the text input div to autosize with the text input to be 100% of the text div.

Is this possible? I think I've given enough info but am happy to provide any other details needed. I've been working on this for hours and am frustrated at this point.

**EDIT**

I may not have explained the desired behavior clearly enough.

`#container` width changes according to display width. This already happens perfectly. It can be 960px width all the way down to 320px width.

`#btn` is not a fixed width. It will be positioned all the way to the right margin of `#container`.

`#text` width needs to autosize to take up the entire width between `#container`'s left and `#btn`'s right margins.

Comment: Is the width of the button fixed or unknown?

Comment: Try to this http://jsfiddle.net/5Hrsc/

Comment: salman: The button width is unknown.

Comment: Rohit Azad: The text field would need to autosize to 100% of the #text div. I tried adding `#text { width: 100%; }` but that didn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use old school tables for this. The following should provide you a starting point:

a) Add a wrapper div that acts as table row:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="temp">
        <div id="text"><input type="text" /></div>
        <div id="btn"><input type="submit" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

b) Set the divs to display as `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell`

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#temp {
    display: table-row;
}
#text, #btn {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

c) Set the width of the first cell to `100%`; this makes the cell as wide as possible while keeping the other cells as narrow as possible:

```
#text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

d) Set the input box to `100%` as well:

```
#text input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

e) Improve.

[Demo with ids replaced with classes](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/B46wu/)

Answer (score 1):

try this

**css**

```
<style>
  #container { width: 100%; }
  #text { float: left; width:70%;}
  #btn { float: left; overflow: hidden; width:30%; }
  .res
  {
      width:100%;

  }
</style>
```

**html code**

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="text"><input type="text" class="res"/></div>
    <div id="btn"><input type="submit" class="res" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: On a mobile (smaller display) the button will not display right. I don't think I can specify a width on the button.

Comment: #container gets as wide as 960px. In that case there is 560px gap between #text and #btn. I really don't think I can set the width on the button and #text needs to autosize to the difference between #container width minus #btn width. There should be no gap between #text and #btn.

Comment: you don't want gap between #text and #btn a?

Comment: Right. The button is floated to the right. Only #text width should change.

Comment: Boopathi, I really do appreciate your diligence. Thank you for sure. It's just that the button width can't change otherwise it will not match the rest of the site's buttons. If the page display is 960px width and #btn is set to 30%, the button will be almost 300px wide and that would look hideous. Likewise, if the display width drops to 320px and #btn is 30%, it will not be wide enough. I have tried messing with #btn's width, but it needs to be left alone or it just won't look very good.

Comment: The only things that should autosize on width are #text and it's text input field. I edited my question, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

used to this

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="btn"><input type="submit" /></div>
    <div id="text"><input type="text" /></div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
#container {  }
  #btn { float: right; }
#text{

    background:green;
    margin-right:100px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hrsc/2/)**

Comment: text input does not autosize to fill #text div

Comment: In your fiddle, the text input drops below the button making 2 horizontal rows instead of all on a single horizontal row.

Comment: Also, `#text {margin-right: 100px;}` assumes the button has a fixed width of 100px. The button does not have a fixed width. I need the button to float with its right margin all the way to the right of #container and its left margin all the way to the right of #text. Lol, hope I'm saying that right!